# Materialize Modals don't open again when form doesn't pass validation

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'm working with MaterializeCSS and using its Modals components.

I am validating login information with jQuery like this:

```
$(".login-form").submit(function(event){
 if ($("input.username").val() === 0 | $("input.password").val() === 0){
     event.preventDefault(); // Avoids sending form data
     $("#login").openModal(); // Modal should open again. This works when it's called on $(document).ready         
 }
});
```

Modal shows up for a moment but then it disappears.
Is there something am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

By the way, `$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();` is the first instruction when `$(document).ready()` function is executed.

Thanks.